# Node.js | Getting a specific page from a pdf file

Tags: node.js, express, pdf

I am looking for a way that when the client enters the address `/file?file=x.pdf&page=10` he will receive back only page 10 from the x.pdf file.

I use Node.js & Express.js.
Does anyone have an idea?

I tried using the pdf-parse library and it returned me only the text of the page, I'm looking to get the page itself, not the text.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just break the PDF into one file per page? You can do this online for free with [PDFEscape](https://www.pdfescape.com/) or with Adobe Acrobat Pro DC, if you are a Creative Cloud subscriber. I think you can also do it w/ photo shop and maybe Google Drive as well.

EDIT 2/27/2023:

I have a solution for you. It's a free C++ library called `qpdf`. There's also a command-line executable you can get for any platform.

For Ubuntu:
`apt -y install qpdf`

This will install the `qpdf` binary as well as `libqpdf28`, which you can use in your code. But if you're using express/node, you could just do a system call to the CLI tool.

Here's an example of you you could do this on CLI (tested):

```bash
qpdf --empty inputfile.pdf 5 -- inputfile_page5.pdf
```

Weird CLI arguments, but it works like a champ! Hope this works for you. I agree creating all those file would be cumbersome.

More Reading:

[Docs](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

[Man Page](https://www.mankier.com/1/qpdf)

Comment: It will take a lot of resources.
There are 1000 files, each file contains about 800 pages.

Comment: Use a CDN service like [AWS CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) backed by an S3 bucket, both of which have a free-tier with generous limits. I have thousands of files and still don't pay a penny. I wrote a [blog article](https://designly.biz/blog/post/how-to-use-aws-cloudfront-to-create-your-own-free-cdn) on the subject.

Comment: Hey, I found a solution for you. Updated my original answer (preserved for posterity).